# Find the closest record in a Spark RDD for Each Record in Another RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geolocation, geospatial, rdd

I have two massive RDDs, and for each record in one, I need to find the physically closest (lat/lon) point in the other that has the same `key`.  But...  in each RDD, there are 100's of millions of records with the same `key`, so I can't do a full join on `key`.  Any distance calc's need to be limited to somewhat local points in the other dataset.

Here's a simplified (for clarity, and since there's no memory constraints in stackoverflow) version of what I do today...  but I'd like to see if there's a better way.  Less memory, faster, better?

Let's start out with data that looks like this:

```
case class Meta(key: Any, lat: Double, lon: Double, meta: Any)

case class Data(key: Any, lat: Double, lon: Double, data: Any, meta: Option[Any] = None) { 
  def ingestMeta(m: Option[Meta]) = this.copy(meta = m) 
}

val rddMeta: RDD[Meta] = ???
val rddData: RDD[Data] = ???
```

The way I try to localize the distance calculations is hard to explain.  For the Meta (smaller dataset) I duplicate each record 9x and snap them to truncated (Integer) lat/lon's at the truncated lat/lon of the Meta record and also +/- 1 degree on each truncated lat/lon.

So...  if the real Meta point is the red dot, and each box is a 1 degree x 1 degree box with Int lat/lon as it's center, I duplicate the Meta at all 9 of the blue dots.

[image]

See this modification to the Meta class, which adds the `threeDegreeBox` method:

```
case class Meta(key: Any, lat: Double, lon: Double, meta: Any) {
  def threeDegreeBox: List[((Any, Int, Int), Meta)] = {
      for { 
        lt <- List(lat.toInt - 1, lat.toInt, lat.toInt + 1)
        ln <- List(lon.toInt - 1, lon.toInt, lon.toInt + 1) 
      } yield ((key, lt, ln), this)
    }

  // distance calc
  def haversine(otherLat: Double, otherLon: Double): Double = ???
}
```

So how does this help?

First, I've reduced the joins from all Meta records with the same key, to just the Meta records with the same key within 1 to 2 degrees of the Data records.  In reality, I don't want anything even 1 degree away.  60 km is plenty, so this still brings back far too many candidates, but it's better than missing one.

So here I collect each Meta record with a given key in a Integer-ized location.

```
// RDD[((key, truncLat, truncLon), Iterable[Meta])]
val rddMetaBoxed: RDD[((Any, Int, Int), Iterable[Meta])] =
  rddMeta
    .flatMap(_.threeDegreeBox)
    .groupByKey
```

Then I truncate lat/lon in the Data as well to join.  Since I've duplicated the Meta 9x to surrounding locations, this join should pull in everything within 150-ish km.  Then I just iterate through all the Meta records and perform a distance calc (on actual, non-truncated lat/lon's) on each to find the closest and ingest the Meta.

```
// perform the same truncation on rddData to join
val result: RDD[Meta] = 
  rddData
    .keyBy( d => (d.key, d.lat.toInt, d.lon.toInt) )
    .leftOuterJoin( rddMetaBoxed ) // maybe inner join and dump non-matches
    .map { case ((key, lt, ln), (data, optionIterableMeta)) => 
      // use the distance calc to find the closest Meta in the Iterable
      val closest: Option[Meta] = ???
      data.ingestMeta(closest) 
    }
```

It works, but it's hassle to actually get it running and I need to throw in a bunch of hacky stuff to avoid memory issues.  There's gotta be an easier/smarter way to do this.  Anybody have any ideas/advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Geohash for this.

It would have the same properties of your `(Any, Int, Int)` key except it's a string, with well defined properties.

So take an `RDD[Meta]` and turn it into `RDD[(Meta, Seq[String])]` flatMap into `RDD[(String, Meta)]` groupBy the string into `RDD[(String, Seq[Meta])` and use a join and filter to find the closest point.

It's obviously very similar to what you came up with, except with a simpler key

Comment: I use a geohash (specifically my own GeoHex fork) a lot in this same project, so I'm very open to this. The problem I run into w/ GeoHex is that if the sample is near the edge of the hex, and the closest piece of meta is in the adjacent hex, I miss it...  and determining all nearby hexes that fall in a bounding box around each meta point is more computationally expensive than just truncating lat/lon and doing +/- 1, although maybe using a smaller search area than 3 degrees by 3 degrees would be a benefit.  Are there other geohash libs that might be better suited to this overall task?

Comment: I see Geohash is something specific, not just a general concept where GeoHex would be an implementation.  My mistake.  I'll take a look and it does seem like maybe it would simplify and give more control over the size of the bounding box.